# Questioning received JSON structure

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I'm currently using a beta API (http://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods) which returns JSON for all the exposed methods.
I've been able to use JSON.NET to deserialize all of these return values so far. However, today I consumed one of their function which returns a JSON that is valid but is in my opinion not correct.

You're probably wondering, why don't you ask it on the beta forum? I have but I haven't received an answer so far and in general this intrigues me.

A snippet of the JSON return:

```
    "1001": {
     "name": "Boots of Speed",
     "plaintext": "Slightly increases Movement Speed",
     "group": "BootsNormal",
     "description": "<...
    }
```

The problem I have with this structure is that the ID is used as a "group" without an identifier. I would be able to use this decently if it had

```
"ItemID" : "1001"
```

But it doesn't have that. I don't mind manually parsing it but I'd first like to know whether or not this JSON is correct (not just valid).

Do you agree that this is not a clean way of creating a JSON block that contains a list of elements or am I missing something here? So far I haven't seen any comments on the beta forum of this API so I'm really wondering why.

Edit "valid" vs "correct/usable":
I know it's a valid JSON statement. I'm questioning the fact whether this is usable with JSON.NET.

I have the following class definition (with two subclasses):

```
public class JSONItem
{
    [JsonProperty("tags")]
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("plaintext")]
    public string Plaintext { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("into")]
    public string[] Into { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("image")]
    public JSONItemImage Image { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("colloq")]
    public string Colloq { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gold")]
    public JSONItemGold Gold { get; set; }
}
```

When giving the above JSON block to to JSONConvert.DeserializeObject(json) it throws an error because "1001" is not mentioned in JSONItem.
How do you handle this so that you can use JSON.NET?

A class like this won't work because you have no names to give the properties:

```
public class JSONItemWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("")]
    public JSONItem MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: "consistent with other methods"
The other methods return blocks where every property is within {} and has an identifier. The most recently added function have this "primary key outside of {}" style.

Comment: `"1001"` is the key of an entry in an object, assuming this is enclosed in `{ ... }`

Comment: And the rest of it is a subobject that's the value of this entry.

Comment: This gave to me a syntax error: `JSON.parse('"ItemID" : "1001"');`

Comment: It's valid JSON. Whether I agree or not is not really the issue. The bigger question would be is this consistent with their other API results...

Comment: for me is perfectly valid, the key is "1001" and the value is another json object

Comment: In my understanding if `JSON.parse` can't understand it is not valid. However `JSON.parse("{\"ItemID\" : \"1001\"}");` was parsed fine.

Comment: See comments on post of L.B.
Thank you all for the swift response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a valid json and you can use  a type like `Dictionary<string, SomeObject>` to deserialize your json.

```
string json = @"{
    ""1001"": {
            ""name"": ""Boots of Speed"",
            ""plaintext"": ""Slightly increases Movement Speed"",
            ""group"": ""BootsNormal"",
            ""description"": ""desc...""
        }
    }";


var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, MyObject>>(json);
```

and accesing an item later on by its key can be fast too.

---

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string plaintext { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I need to have access to the "1001" field as well as that is the primary key of this Item object. This primary key is referenced to in other objects that their API returns.

Comment: @Starceaker  what is wrong in using `dict.Keys` to get all keys, `dict.Values` to get a list of all items and `dict["1001"]` to access a single item?

Comment: I missed that part, thank you for the explanation L.B. This could very well be the answer I was looking for. I was so focused on deserializing to one object that I forgot I could deserialize to a collection. I will mark as answer in a moment when I've tested it.

Comment: Thank you very much L.B.
You made me a smarter man today :-).

Answer (score 1):

It's annoying when APIs do things like this (using numbers as property names), but all is not lost. Simply deserialize the JSON using Json.NET and then access each of the items using the indexer operator on the parent object.

EDIT:

I almost never create DTOs when deserializing JSON. It's lots of unnecessary boilerplate in most cases. I prefer deserializing to a `dynamic` object, but that won't be as effective when dealing with property names that begin with digits.

Here is how I would deserialize your sample message:

```
using System;

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace JsonExample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            const string json = @"
                {
                    '1001': {
                        'name': 'Boots of Speed',
                        'plaintext': 'Slightly increases Movement Speed',
                        'group': 'BootsNormal',
                        'description': '<...'
                    }
                }";
            var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
            var plaintext = jObject["1001"]["plaintext"].Value<string>();

            Console.WriteLine(plaintext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make this answer a lot better by including some sample code to demonstrate your idea.  This answer sounds pretty hand-wavy as it stands.

Comment: It wasn't my intention to handwave, but you're right about the sample code. Added.

Answer (score 0):

When put into http://JSONLint.com,

```
{
    "1001": {
        "name": "Boots of Speed",
        "plaintext": "Slightly increases Movement Speed",
        "group": "BootsNormal",
        "description": "<..."
    }
}
```

Validates as JSON.

Comment: Yes, it is enclosed in `{}` diferent from what OP posted.

Comment: Yeah, I did have to ad the braces, but OP did say it was a snippet, so I assumed that there was more data in there. I think the question was geared more towards the `"1001":` in the JSON.

Comment: Correct Justin C. I need to be able to deserialze the block, including the "1001". The structure we receive now is making it more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: See comment in L.B.'s answer. Using a Dictionary was the trick I needed.